How does temperature affect the deflection of a Bimetallic Strip
Suppose I have a bimetallic strip clamped onto a horizontal, with linear thermal expansion coefficients of $\alpha_A$ and $\alpha_B$ of metal A and B respectively; assume $\alpha_A > \alpha_B$. How could I determine the amount of deflection with a given temperature $\Delta T$ and initial length $x$?
After a temperature $\Delta T$, metal A would expand
$$x_A = x\alpha_A \Delta T +x = x(1+\alpha_A \Delta T)$$
and metal B
$$x_B = x(1+\alpha_B \Delta T)$$
From here, how would I calculate the deflection $\delta$, with a given temperature difference, as shown in the following figure?


There are several formulas of various levels of complexity (depending on, for example, whether the resulting arc can be approximated by a parabola, in the case of small deflections). You can do an online search for "bimetallic strip" timoshenko for discussions and comparisons of these.

The analysis I gave in my answer leads to the final results presented here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimetallic_strip

A simple approach is to consider the bimetalic deflection as a simple arc:


After a temperature $\Delta T$, metal A would expand
$$x_A = x\alpha_A \Delta T +x = x(1+\alpha_A \Delta T)$$
and metal B
$$x_B = x(1+\alpha_B \Delta T)$$

Converting these to arc lengths gives
$$x_A = r_2\theta \text{ and } x_B = r_1\theta$$
If the thickness of the two metals is equal then:
$$ r_1 = R + \frac d 2 \text{ and } r_2 = R - \frac d 2$$
$$x_A = \left(R + \frac d 2\right)\theta \text{ and } x_B = \left(R - \frac d 2\right)\theta$$
Adding the two lengths gives: $$ x_A + x_B = 2R\theta$$ and $$ \theta = \frac{x_A + x_B}{2R}$$
Subtracting the two lengths gives:
$$x_A - x_B = d\theta$$ which leads to
$$ R = \frac d 2 \left(\frac{x_A + x_B}{x_A - x_B}\right)$$
Finally, substituting $x_A$ and $x_B$ gives;
$$R = \frac d 2 \left(\frac{2+(\alpha_A + \alpha_B)\Delta T}{(\alpha_A -\alpha_B)\Delta T}\right)$$
This is a first order approximation but demonstrates the basic behavior of a bimetallic strip.

But this doesn't tell us anything about the temperature.

This doesn’t account for the bending stiffness of the strip nor does it satisfy the constraint that the two layers are bonded together at their interface.

I like the simple approach. The rest is engineering.

What we are dealing with here is a laminated composite structure.  This can be analyzed by representing the deformation as a linear combination axial stretching and bending.  In this analysis, we assume that the two layers are of equal thickness h.
Step 1:  Assuming that each layer experiences the same axial strain (since the two layers are glued together), the axial stresses in the two layers are $$\sigma_1=E_1(\epsilon-\alpha_1\Delta T)$$and$$\sigma_2=E_2(\epsilon-\alpha_2\Delta T)$$where $\epsilon$ is the axial strain of both layers.  Using the condition that the total axial force from the two layers is zero, we have that $$E_1(\epsilon-\alpha_1\Delta T)+E_2(\epsilon-\alpha_2\Delta T)=0$$The solution to this equation for the uniform axial strain $\epsilon$ is $$\epsilon=\frac{\alpha_1E_1+\alpha_2E_2}{E_1+E_2}\Delta T$$In addition, the stresses in the two layers are $$\sigma_1=\frac{E_1E_2(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)}{E_1+E_2}\Delta T$$and$$\sigma_2=\frac{E_1E_2(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)}{E_1+E_2}\Delta T$$If layer 1 has a higher thermal expansion coefficient than layer 2, layer 1 will be in compression and layer 2 will be in tension.  Even though this gives a zero axial force, it gives an axial couple at all locations of $$M=\frac{E_1E_2(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)}{E_1+E_2}h^2\Delta T$$
Step 2:  In order for axial force and bending moment of the composite strip to be zero. we must add (superimpose) a bending strain to the strain calculated in part 1, such that it adds no net axial tension to the result in part 1, but exactly cancels the bending moment in part 1. Such a bending strain can be shown geometrically to have the form $$\epsilon=\frac{y-y_0}{R}$$where y is measured upward from the center plane of the bimetallic strip, $y_0$ is the vertical location of the "neutral surface", and R is the radius of curvature of the strip.  The conditions necessary to complete step 2 are $$\int_{-h}^0{E_2\frac{y-y_0}{R}dy}+\int_{0}^h{E_1\frac{y-y_0}{R}dy}=0$$and$$\int_{-h}^0{E_2\frac{y-y_0}{R}ydy}+\int_{0}^h{E_1\frac{y-y_0}{R}ydy}=-M$$The first of these two equations can be used to determine the location of the neutral axis, and the second equation can be used to determine the bending radius.

The analysis I gave leads to the final results presented here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimetallic_strip

How about the mechanical properties of the glue?

By glued together, I meant bonded together.
